# Sum over a range with start and end point variables in R

Tags: r, range

I have a dataframe with the following variables:

```
start_point    end_point    variable_X
     1             5           0.3757
     2             7           0.4546       
     3             7           0.1245 
     4             8           0.3455
     5             11          0.2399 
     6             12          0.0434
     7             15          0.4323
     ...           ...           ...
```

I would like to add a fourth column that sums variable X from the start point to the end points defined in the first two columns, i.e. the entry in the first row would be the sum between 1 and 5 (inclusive): 0.3757+0.4546+0.1245+0.3455+0.2399 = 1.5402, the entry in second row would be sum between 2 and 7 (inclusive): 0.4546+0.1245+0.3455+0.2399+0.0434+0.4323 = 1.6402 and so forth.

I'm new to R, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, these are both good answers that work well.

Comment: Actually, there is an issue when I applied to another data set. In there, the last few rows did not have an endpoint, i.e. were filled with NAs. Both solutions are refusing to provide any outputs, Error NA/NaN argument is popping up. Happy for sum for these runs to equal NA.

Comment: Then you can use a simple `ifelse` (in both solutions, I updated mine to address this). This shows that it is important to provide a good reproducible example when you ask a question ;-) --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Duly noted on including all the fine details in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr`, using another reproducible example to address the situation with `NA`'s in `end_point` as in the OP's comment (with `ifelse`):

```
# Reproducible example
mydf = data.frame(start_point = 1:9,
                  end_point = c(5, NA, 7, 8, 11, 12, 7, 15, NA),
                  variable_X = c(1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 2))

library(dplyr)
mydf %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sumX = ifelse(is.na(end_point), NA, sum(mydf$variable_X[start_point:end_point])))

#   start_point end_point variable_X  sumX
#         <int>     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
# 1           1         5          1    16
# 2           2        NA          5    NA
# 3           3         7          2    16
# 4           4         8          3    15
# 5           5        11          5    NA
# 6           6        12          4    NA
# 7           7         7          2     2
# 8           8        15          1    NA
# 9           9        NA          2    NA
```

Answer (score 3):

There are probably slicker ways to do this, but here's a quick version:

```
df$sumX <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(df$variable_X[x[1]:x[2]]))
df

  start_point end_point variable_X   sumX
1           1         5     0.3757 1.5402
2           2         7     0.4546 1.6402
3           3         7     0.1245 1.1856
4           4         8     0.3455     NA
5           5        11     0.2399     NA
6           6        12     0.0434     NA
7           7        15     0.4323     NA
```

The last few rows are `NA` here because I don't have rows 8 through 15 of your data.